# PHP SQL UPDATE query returning true but not update in DB

Tags: php, mysqli

There are quite a few answers to this question but they are all a little different from mine.

I'm having trouble updating a column. The query returns true but no changes have been made in database. When I run the same query in phpMyAdmin, it's working perfectly so I think the the error is with my php code.

```
        $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

        if($con){
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `tickets` SET `logged_in`= 0 WHERE `id` = " . $user_id;

            $res = $con->query($sql);

            if($res){


                   $_SESSION =  array();
                   session_destroy();
                   header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/?logged_out' );
            } else {
                   echo($con->error);
               }
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around the cause of the error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Chk session... print_r($_SESSION);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `tickets` SET `logged_in`= 0 WHERE `id` = $user_id";
```

Comment: Why try this? An answer should always have an explanation. This also appears to be the same code the OP is using..

Comment: It worked. But an explanation would really be appreciated. Like what's the difference between what you did and what I did?

Comment: There is no difference in both queries

Comment: Double quotes end the query, so the variable was not passed to the query.

Comment: It would process the exact same. PHP concatenates then sends to DB. DB sees it the same.

Comment: @MelvinRufetu this answer would make no difference. If this worked you may have some transient issue with your database.

Comment: @Martin the query is **exactly the same as OP**. Try yourself: https://eval.in/522704

Comment: @chris85 - exactly this. Nothing 'executes' until the semicolon.